# Amazon S3 query using regular expression

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I have the following folder structure in S3.

```
myBucket/20190313/20190313_100000/_SUCCESS
```

I need to check whether there is `_SUCCESS` File present

Query I am currently using:

```
date = 20190313
bucket = s3Resource.Bucket(myBucket)
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=date+'/'))
```

I do not know what will be inside of the date folder. But is in `yyyymmdd_hhmmss` format.

Is there a way to query for that specific "_SUCCESS" file, if only "myBucket/20190313/" is known?

Comment: There are no folders in S3 or any other cloud storage provider. Folders require recursion which doesn't scale when a container is expected to hold millions of files. Folders are *emulated* by treating the `/` character as a delimiter. Prefix "queries" are the only kind of "query" that can actually run fast - the service just filters out all items that start with that prefix, possibly by spreading the filtering operations to multiple servers

Comment: That's why non-prefix queries actually run on the *client*, ie your machine - without a prefix the service has no idea which "partition" holds your data so it has to search *everything*. Even S3 SDK functions that seem to do otherwise, actually pull all data retruned by the prefix part of a query and filter the results on the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long shot, depending on your object keys, but you could combine the `prefix` and the `delimiter` properties.

e.g.:

```
Prefix = date+'/'
Delimiter = '_'
```

As I'm sure that you are aware, there is no folder structure in S3 keys, rather a unique string to identify the object. The use of a delimiter of '/' creates a hierarchy, or more of a virtual folder structure.

Use of the delimiter property will change the virtual folder structure from using '/' to '_'. Provided that you don't use underscores in other keys, it will return a collection of strings between the end of the prefix, and the start of the next prefix, i.e. the '_' in '_SUCCESS'

Comment: Yes I used '/' as the delimiter and it gives the list of all folder inside the bucket!

Answer (score 1):

The [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) says that you cant use a regex

> Limits the response to keys that **begin with the specified prefix**. You can use prefixes to separate a bucket into different groupings of keys. (You can think of using prefix to make groups in the same way you would use a folder in a file system.)

Comment: That paragraph says that a regex *can't* be used, only a prefix